# Spring boot behave different when running using jar file compare to running in IDE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jar, kotlin

I create a simple spring boot application using [start.spring.io](http://start.spring.io) with only one dependency: Web Services (Gradle, springBoot:2.0.3, Kotlin). then I add the following file as a controller.

```
@Controller
public class WelcomeController {
    private static final String welcomemsg = "Welcome Mr. %s!";

    @GetMapping("/welcome/user")
    @ResponseBody
    public Welcome welcomeUser(@RequestParam(name = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "Java Fan") String name) {
        return new Welcome(String.format(welcomemsg, name));
    }
}
```

and then run the main class in IntelliJ and everything goes fine. and I could access `localhost:8080/welcome/user?name=X`.

when I run `bootJar` it gives me an executable jar file under `build/libs` directory. when I run it, Spring boot application starts without error but I can not access `/welcome/user/` and it returns 404 error. what's wrong with these steps?

I Notice that the following log exists when I run it in IDE but doesn't exist when I run Jar file.

> 2018-07-09 11:13:53.873  INFO 22042 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/welcome/user],methods=[GET]}" onto public ir.hosseinnasr.sarbazi.Welcome ir.hosseinnasr.sarbazi.WelcomeController.welcomeUser(java.lang.String)

when I look at my jar, file structure It seems ok, it contains my controller class.

Comment: welcom != welcome

Comment: Which view technology are you using.

Comment: Do you see in the startup logs something like `.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/welcome/user],methods=[GET]` ?

Comment: @Thoomas I see `s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/welcome/user] ...` when I run in IDE but this line doesn't exists when I run using jar file.

Comment: @M.Deinum I'm only add `spring-boot-starter-web-services` dependency to my project using start.spring.io. I test this behavior with another REST framework (Jersey) and i face the same problem with it.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks, I fix my typo in the question.

Comment: `spring-boot-starter-web-services` has nothing to do with ReST that is for SOAP based webservices.

Comment: You may be missing a web container dependancy ?

Comment: @M.Deinum, I completely understand it, but at this point, my problem is why it works in IDE and doesn't with Jar file. I face the similar issue with jersey.

Comment: @Thoomas, I don't thinks so. Its embedded in spring boot and i see tomcat jar files in my final jar too.